# Using the same action on multiple sprites?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, action

I want to create an action once, then add it to multiple sprites.  For example, I have a 'monster' that gets a bunch of legs added to its body.  Each of these legs are children of the body, and I want them to rotate back and forth.  I made a `CCRepeatForever` of a sequence of two `CCRotateBy` actions which works great.  I can add the action to a leg, but if I then add it to a different leg, the first leg doesn't rotate.

I don't want to make a new sequence for each leg - what a pain!  There's gotta be an easy way!

EDIT:

I implemented it like this, per gixdev and Lukman's answers...  (thanks AGAIN Lukman!)

```
[leg1 runAction:action]; // for the first time using the action
[leg2 runAction:[[action copy] autorelease]]; // for all subsequent uses
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If copy your once created actions it help you

```
[leg1 runAction:[action copy]];
[leg2 runAction:[action copy]];
...
```

Comment: You need to `release` what you `copy`, thus I'd suggest `[leg1 runAction:[[action copy] autorelease]];` instead ;)

Comment: Just to be clear though, the original `CCAction` needs to be created with `alloc` and `init`, or made as a `property` to be reused throughout a program in this way - else it'll be autoreleased itself, and not available to be `copied`, right?